# Parametric Simulation of FX forwards

Tags: fx, forward-rate

I need to simulate FX forwards for risk management (VaR) purposes. The problem is that the FX forwards are derived from : 
1) Spot 
2) int rates 
3) and the basis.

So the question is how do you simulate the whole lot together? In reality, I may have up to 6 currencies in my portfolio with tenors ranging from 6 months to 6 years.

Comment: I am not sure what actually did you mean by "parametric" simulation. I thought there were only Historical or Monte Carlo simulations. Can you please expand?